# REST API For exact target. Add subscribers to lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, list

We have a email subscribe form that will add users to Email lists they select in the interface.

I am trying to find REST API documentation for Exact Target that will allow us to do the following:
1. Create a new user
2. Find a user
3. Add user to a list(s)
4. Get all lists for a user.

We have this all working in SOAP. 
However, it is VERY slow.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: There isn't a rest route for subscribers, but based on the number of calls you are making, SOAP would be slow. Are you trying to do all four steps at one time, or are these separate calls made at different times? Could you maybe provide the soap request envelopes in a gist as well?